# How to bulk_update in related fields modified using only one call

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm working with two tables to change some data in there but I'm wanted to avoid two calls using `bulk_update` as following:

```py
queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
submodels_to_update = []
for instance in queryset:
    instance.submodel = process()
    instance.submodel.sub_property = some_random_data()
    submodels_to_update.append(instance.submodel)

MyModel.objects.bulk_update(queryset, ['submodel'])
SubModel.objects.bulk_update(submodels_to_update, ['sub_property'])
```

What I wanted to do is something like the following:

```
MyModel.objects.bulk_update(queryset, ['submodel', 'submodel__sub_property'])
```

But `bulk_update` seems like not support related_fields using the ORM syntax. My question here is if there is a way to achieve `bulk_update` in two different tables at the same time.

If the answer is that it is not possible I don't have any problem to accept that, just share the relevant links that prove that the approach that I'm describing here is not supported.

Comment: I have tried `MyModel.objects.bulk_update(queryset, ['submodel', 'submodel__sub_property'])` but didn't worked. I searched in the documentation but not say anything about related_fields in bulk_update.

Comment: why do you want one call for two diff tables?
whats the problem in making two diff calls for two diff models?

Comment: I'm exploring  a way to just make one call to the database... If I use two bulk_update functions that is two calls to the database.

Comment: If you are doing this for speed reasons - maybe have a look at `django-fast-update`. (And nope, thats not possible with bulk_update, it would even resort on its own to multiple UPDATE statements for nonlocal fields from multitable inheritance.)

Comment: Can you share official documentation where pointed that  `bulk_update` works just for local fields and not for related fields? I agree with you that it is not possible but I haven't found anything clear in the documentation that indicate that.

Comment: Its stated for `update` "The update() method is applied instantly, and the only restriction on the QuerySet that is updated is that it can only update columns in the model’s main table, not on related models." Internally `bulk_update` uses `update`.

Comment: You are right @jerch I realized that because in the documentation it says: `updates the given fields on the provided model instances`. So that means that it doesn't work with related fields that exists in other models.

Comment: Don't get confused with `update` method, I'm talking about `bulk_update`.

Comment: Feel free to answer this question providing documentation and I will accept it @jerch.

Comment: Well your passage explains it indirectly (if one knows that a __ related model access is a different model instance), but the real reason behind it is that `update` cannot do that, as I referred from its docs. And no I am not confusing `bulk_update` with `update`, the first uses the latter internally, thus has the same underlying restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/)

> This method efficiently updates the given fields on the provided model instances, generally with one query, and returns the number of objects updated.

Notice: `updates the given fields on the provided model instances` It can only update fields on the provided model instances. As @jerch pointed out

> The `update()` method is applied instantly, and the only restriction on the QuerySet that is updated is that **it can only update columns in the model’s main table, not on related models.**" Internally bulk_update uses `update` method and that's why the restriction.